# How to spy on AI players?

Tags: civilization-5

Long long time ago in the original Civilization, there was a cheat that allowed one to not only see the whole map but more importantly — see how AI players developed.

Is there any way to watch the AI development in Civilization 5?

Answer (score 1):

Firetuner lets you see everything that is happening as well as modifying it.  It is part of the Civ 5 SDK.  Download it from the Tools menu in Steam.  Start up the SDK, and choose Firetuner.  Once it starts, load up Civ 5 like you normally would.  Once you are in game, switch back to Firetuner.

Describing everything that Firetuner can do would take a book.  A few highlights:

- The Selected City tab will let you look at any city and what buildings it has.
- Going to the Map tab and pressing "Reveal Terrain" will remove the Fog of War completely.  It also lets you add units anywhere.
- The Game tab lets you autoplay turns or take over a different power.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to spy on your opponents, once the expansion [Gods & Kings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_V:_Gods_%26_Kings) is released sometime in Quarter 2, then espionage shall be possible. Although you shall find that spies in the upcoming expansion will be a bit different then in past Civ games.

Comment: I don't think he is talking about spy units, I think he is referring to "cheat mode" that allows you to see everything all the time.

Comment: Yes, i've heard about add-on, but now i want just to see what AI player do to grow so fast.

Comment: @Maaboo they grow by going heavy into population increase.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know of to do this in Civ5 is to save the game, `retire` or `quit` and to use the maps and statistics to see where the AI players are up to.

There is even a time elapsed mode that allows you to see events, city placement and wars via seeing the cities being taken or razed.

After you have `cheated`, you load the game back up.